# find a value in a column every time typed-in, and find it in another sheet, and color it?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets;
In the first one ("codes") I have some labels that are numbers and strings together with a hyphen, like `AA-01`.
In the second sheet ("places") I have list of all labels in different rows and columns everywhere.

I need to write a code to ONCE receive a label in sheet "code", find it in sheet "places" and color it.
That should be something like onEdit, and once I get that label erased, I need the cell in the second sheet ("places") get back to white background again.
So this is like a live process; when I type in a label in first sheet, I want this process happen and it finds the value in second sheet and just color it.

I have made this, but not sure why is not working!

```
function color() {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('places');
  var sheet       = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('codes'); 
  var ToPlace     = sheet.getRange("F13:F300").getValues();
  var targetCell  = targetSheet.getRange("A1:Z").getValues();


  for(var i = 0; i < toPlace.length; i++) {
    if( toPlace[i] == targetCell){  
      targetSheet.setBackground("yellow"); 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you declared `ToPlace`, but in the for loop and inside is used as `toPlace`

Comment: Basically you want to stream a change in one sheet onto another?

Comment: Yes. My first sheet ("codes"), is changing always (in column F13:F).  Some values are entered and some get erased, like every hour. On the other side, in my second sheet ("places"), I do have like a fixed database but in different cells and columns of all those labels in the sheet "code" which are in column F13:F, and I want to see them with a color background .

Answer (score 0):

You are currently iterating through the rows of the codes getting Arrays of strings.
You are then comparing those arrays to targetCell which is an Array of Arrays of Strings.

You can doe something like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('places');
  var targetCells = targetSheet.getRange("A1:Z").getValues();

  for (var row = 0; row < targetSheet.getLastRow(); row++) {
    for (var col = 0; col < targetSheet.getLastColumn(); col++) {
      if (targetCells[row][col] === e.value) {
        targetSheet.getRange(row+1, col+1).setBackground("yellow");
        return;
      } else if (targetCells[row][col] === e.oldValue) {
        targetSheet.getRange(row+1, col+1).setBackground("white");
      }
    }
  }  
}
```